# Reflection: Read List-type properties of an object, containing another object

Tags: c#, list, object, reflection, propertyinfo

I am trying to serialize nested objects using reflection. I am able to do this fine for properties containing a single value, but I am having trouble with list type properties that contain another class.

In the code sample below I have a class `Dish` which contains a list of of `Recipe` classes as a property, which itself contains a list of `Step` classes.

I am able to get the `PropertyInfo` of the List property, but when I try to get the contents of it by invoking the get method, I get a simple object back, not a List of e.g. Steps:

```
var listObjects =  property.GetGetMethod().Invoke(dish, null);
```

I managed to cast that into a List of objects like this:

```
List<object> listValues = ( listObjects as IEnumerable<object>).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Now at least I can iterate over this List, but I cannot get the acutal properties of the original classes like the step description.

So I know the type of the List via `property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First()`, but its at runtime. I am thinking on how to perform a proper cast to transform my `List<object>` into a conrete type like `List<Step>`.

What I want to achieve: Serialize all property values of `dish` and all its attached Lists of objects.

I appreciate any ideas.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dish = new Dish(){
                 Recipes = new List<Recipe>(){
                           new Recipe(){
                               RecipeName = "Preparation", 
                               Steps = new List<Step>(){
                                       new Step(){
                                       Description = "Prepare Stuff",
                                       }
                               }
                           },
                           new Recipe(){
                           RecipeName = "Main Course",
                           Steps = new List<Step>(){
                                   new Step(){
                                      Description = "Do this",
                                   },
                                   new Step(){
                                      Description = "Then do that",
                                   }
                               }
                      }, }, };

        var serializer = new Serializer();
        serializer.SerializeDish(dish);
    }
}

public class Serializer
{
    public void SerializeDish(Dish dish)
    {
        var dishType = typeof (Dish);
        var listProps = dishType.GetProperties().Where(x => (x.PropertyType.IsGenericType && x.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (List<>)));
        foreach (var property in listProps)
        {
            var propertyGetMethod = property.GetGetMethod();
            var listObjects = propertyGetMethod.Invoke(dish, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Name:"+property.Name + " " + "List-Type:"+property.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments.First());

            //Here its getting fuzzy
            List<object> listValues = ( listObjects as IEnumerable<object>).Cast<object>().ToList();
            foreach ( var item in listValues ) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Dish
{
    public List<Recipe> Recipes {get;set;}
}

public class Recipe
{
    public string RecipeName{get;set;}
    public List<Step> Steps {get;set;}
}

public class Step
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: My recommendation is to use existing serialization methods like JSON, XML, or binary. They're customizable. The reason is that they've already taken all of this into account. Otherwise what happens is that you modify your classes by adding more nested collections or lists and then you have to update your serialization. Or you write your serialization so well that it really does account for anything, but in that case you're really duplicating lots of existing work.

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion, but I serialize to RDF Triples in the end, so thats not really an option for me. dotnetrdf doesn't provide help in this case

Comment: Since you mention that you have to serialize to RDF Triples then you are writing your custom serializer, I guess. Then at compile time you already know which type of property what class has. Then do you have to actually use Reflection? Or you need a dynamic serializer which needs to accomodate any kind of class?

Comment: Yes, its going to be a custom, dynamic RDF serializer. At the moment I know which classes/properties to expect, but there will be additional ones in the upcoming future, so I want to accomodate for that.